# How to render a wire frame in Rajawali without changing indices data

Tags: render, wireframe, rajawali

I have an Rajawali Object3D initiated with given vertex and index data. Index data describes triangles of the shape. I need to render a wire frame of the shape, but object3D.setRenderMode(GLES20.GL_LINES) uses given triangle indices and the shape is built wrongly. Is there any opportunity to render a wire frame without calculating a new index array and passing it to the shape (user will switch the rendering mode very often)? Java3d uses for that PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_FILL and POLYGON_LINE, which is set on the Appearance, and it works exactly as needed. Please could anybody help?

Comment: Fixed the problem by reading in the triangle index data and calculating index array for the GL_LINES mode (a transformation {0,1,2} to {0,1,1,2,2,0}. Then just set the render mode to GL_LINES and that was it.